# ANR OutOfMemory

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I'm using OkHttp for network communication and showing progressbar to show progress progress dismiss once get response.Model classes implements parceable. Im gettig following error not able to understand why it's happening

**Log:**

```
ANR in com.mmt.extranet (com.mmt.extranet/.ui.activity.ManageInventoryActivity)
E/ActivityManager(  493): PID: 8143
E/ActivityManager(  493): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it.  Outbound queue length: 0.  Wait queue length: 2.)
E/ActivityManager(  493): Load: 0.54 / 0.43 / 0.33
E/ActivityManager(  493): CPU usage from 9275ms to 0ms ago:
E/ActivityManager(  493):   126% 8143/com.mmt.extranet: 67% user + 58% kernel / faults: 53632 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):   2.8% 99/adbd: 0.1% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 1338 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):   1.1% 493/system_server: 0.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 91 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):   0.2% 252/vinput: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   0.1% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   0% 16/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   0% 3667/kworker/1:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493): 31% TOTAL: 16% user + 14% kernel + 0% softirq
E/ActivityManager(  493): CPU usage from 2047ms to 2553ms later:
E/ActivityManager(  493):   34% 251/surfaceflinger: 1.8% user + 32% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     12% 251/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 12% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     5.4% 303/DispSync: 0% user + 5.4% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 306/Binder_2: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 474/VSyncThread: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 476/EventThread: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 478/EventThread: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 539/Binder_3: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 1150/Binder_4: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   23% 254/local_opengl: 0% user + 23% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     20% 473/local_opengl: 0% user + 20% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     3.6% 8175/local_opengl: 0% user + 3.6% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   20% 8143/com.mmt.extranet: 11% user + 9.2% kernel / faults: 7 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):     9.2% 8164/RenderThread: 3.7% user + 5.5% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     5.5% 8143/om.mmt.extranet: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     3.7% 8152/JDWP: 3.7% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   11% 493/system_server: 1.9% user + 9.8% kernel / faults: 1 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):     5.8% 567/InputDispatcher: 1.9% user + 3.9% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.9% 520/android.ui: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   3.6% 99/adbd: 0% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 83 minor
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 99/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 450/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 451/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   1.7% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   1.7% 20/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):   1.8% 628/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493):     1.8% 8184/Binder_4: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager(  493): 17% TOTAL: 2.6% user + 9.6% kernel + 4.8% softirq
I/OpenGLRenderer(  493): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

**Network Call:**
 **

```
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, final IOException exception) {
                    LogUtils.enter(TAG, LogUtils.getMethodName());
                    mHashtableOkHttpCall.remove(Integer.valueOf(mTag));
                    if (Thread.interrupted()) {

                        return;
                    }
                    cb.onFailure(request, exception);

                }
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
                    LogUtils.enter(TAG, LogUtils.getMethodName());
                    mHashtableOkHttpCall.remove(Integer.valueOf(mTag));
                    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                        LogUtils.info(TAG, "Thread is interrupted");
                        return;
                    }

                    cb.onResponse(response);

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogUtils.error(TAG, ex.toString(), ex);
        }
```

**

Comment: Did u use a background thread for network communication?

Comment: Post your code, anr = application not responding. It means you're doing long running operations on the main thread.

Comment: I have posted the code look